# XAML - Runtime Exception after Creating a Dependency Property in WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I am working with the Windows 8 developer build. I am attempting to create a basic dependency property. I've used them before in WPF and Silverlight. However, I'm not trying to create one in WinRT without any luck.

```
public static DependencyProperty GPAProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GPA", "double", "MyNamespace.MyClass", new PropertyMetadata(0));
public double GPA
{
  get { return (double)GetValue(GPAProperty); }
  set { SetValue(GPAProperty, value); }
}
```

When I run my code, I get a runtime exception when the app first starts that says:

*A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*

My question is, does this look right? I keep thinking I'm overlooking something. But it all looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change double to Double...

Comment: What about a DateTime property? Are there any caveats there I should be aware of?

Comment: I'd check http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/09/16/WinRT-vs-Silverlight-Part-3-Dependency-Properties.aspx

Seems like the rule for now (pre-Beta Win8) is - remove "System." from base System types and use fully qualified class name including the namespace for custom types. Not sure about other system types.